# MySQL Performance on VPS

Tags: mysql, performance, linode

I am building a Mobile App which uses a backend server to store the data. If I describe it in terms of Relational DB then it is ~10K records (2 or 3 tables). Planning to use Linode VPS to host it (512 MB). I know the question is very broad, but want to get an idea about the performance under load.

Another choice is to use a NoSQL like Redis, but for that need to put up some time to learn.

I already did searching on SO, but no satisfactory answers yet.

PS: This is a side project and i expect to learn the things along the way. But some good pointers would help to speed up the process.

Comment: The amount of data and number of tables has little relevance really. The amount of memory required to perform a query and the number of queries is more important. If it is a simple query with small result sets then you will be fine with the VPS. I use similar spec VPS for several projects and have no performance issues (yet).

Comment: You would need to provide a lot more information. Can you post the actual structures of the tables (what fields there are, what type of table it is, what fields have indicies)? Additionally, can you post sample queries? Essentially, a lot of it comes down to how you are storing the data and what you are retrieving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that you'll have to work on optimizing queries more than looking for some quick fix. I have been working with plenty of projects running on virtual servers with no performance issues if you write the queries in correct manner. Have a read:
http://owaisahussain.blogspot.com/2012/06/yet-another-blog-on-query-optimization.html

Answer (score -1):

Disable InnoDB, that will save you lots of RAM. To do this, have skip-innodb in your my.cnf file.